# How can i continue learning more efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, resources

i have learned basics of python and created some small projects. Somehow i feel am lost and do not know how should i continue learning! I search for tutorials or new things but can not find good ones. Any suggestions from you will be so amazing and i will really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting a project, that has some elements you don't know, so you can learn on the way. I would also suggest using udemy courses, they helped me on my journey.

Starting a project is the most simple way to learn, Here are some tips:

1. Create a project that you and other people will like.
2. Make it open to the world (Github)
3. Fix any bugs that may come up
4. Continue to expand on it. (Expand you project so you can learn)

Udemy Courses I would recommend are https://www.udemy.com/course/complete-python-bootcamp/, and https://www.udemy.com/course/the-python-mega-course/.

Hope this can help you on your journey, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i really appreciate it . I have already two small projects on my Github published and am working still on them :) but i will try to check the link also. i just do my best and hope for the best. Thanks for Welcoming me :)

Comment: Whats your github username btw?